# Using Libraries

Tags: android

I need some advice on how to use Libraries with Android and have the 
following questions.    I have successfully created a project and a number of
libraries and I am able to set the project as libraries and to link the libraries
into my projects and reference the code in the libraries from the projects or other
libraries.

The problem I have is that when I execute the project in the emulator it complains about a 
missing shared library.

So here are my questions

1. If a shared library links to another shared library using eclipse, so I need to manually reference the name of the library in the using libraries manifest file
2. In the case where there is a chain of say 4 libraries that reference each other ( contrived I know ) e.g. Lib A used Lib B, Lib uses Lib C, Lib C uses Lib D.    Is it only necessary to add the reference in the using Lib manifest e.g. Lib C shall have only the ref to the Lib D in its manifest or must I add additional references in the Application Parent Manifest even though Lib4 is not used in the main application parent.
3. Do I need to do something special for Android to package the shared libraries when using the emulator or can anyone explain why I should get a missing shard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1&3:

You don't have to add anything in the AndroidManifest file...Add

```
android.library.reference.1=<library_path>
```

in your default.properties file.That should make android build tool chain to include your library while building the app.

For question 2. just adding the top level library in your app would add all included libraries also.